# Creating a simple controller alias

Tags: yii, alias

I'm not sure I am using the proper terminology, so I will describe what I want to achieve.

I have a controller called ControllerA and want a "virtual" controller called ControllerB to function exactly the same as ControllerA.

Basically I just want the url *site.com/ControllerB* to load up the same page as *site.com/ControllerA* (but not redirect).

Hope my description is clear enough.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about aliases in controllers but you can use 'forward()' to use another controller's action. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#forward-detail. You can just have the actions named in your controller and forward to the other controller actions. The forward will not be a redirect but a reuse.

Comment: @Jorge This seems to be a shot in the right direction. But is it possible to forward all actions without manually specifying each one?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's never neccessary to create two identical controllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a simple URL rule:

```
'controllerA/<a>'   => 'controllerA/<a>',
'controllerB/<a>'   => 'controllerA/<a>',
```

Read more about URL rules here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls

Comment: +1, but you should correct `controllera`, and use `<action:\w+>` instead of `<a>`

Comment: @soju Typo fixed. The `:\w+` is not strictly neccesary. Only if you had more rules that also start with `controllerB` and need to disambiguate. Otherwhise `<a>` is enough. From [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#using-named-parameters): "*<ParamName:ParamPattern> [...] In case when ParamPattern is omitted, it means the parameter should match any characters except the slash /.*"

Comment: I know :) I just think <action:\w+> is proper

Comment: @soju If i have the choice to type something or to leave it away because it's not necessary I usually know what to do ;). To me, less is more.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend ControllerA with ControllerB and provide extended controller name. Next override `getViewPath` method. Attribute `extendedControler` give us basic controller name.

```
class ControllerBController extends ControllerAController
{
    private $extendedControler = 'ControllerA';
    public function getViewPath() {
        $nI = Yii::app()->createController($this->extendedControler);
        return $nI[0]->getViewPath();
    }
}
```

Of course you can use some string modification. Like str_ireplace:

```
class Klient2Controller extends KlientController
{
    public function getViewPath() {
        //We must extract parent class views directory
        $c = get_parent_class($this);
        $c = str_ireplace('Controller', '', $c); //Extract only controller name
        $nI = Yii::app()->createController($c);
        return $nI[0]->getViewPath();
    }
}
```